# Activating form with string (Changeable values)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, openform

I send name of opened form to datagridview in formload. Then when I double click row of this datagridview, I want to activate the form again. But I cannot use this method. What do you prefer?

```
`  private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
        string fname = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        var type = Type.GetType("ProMod." + fname);
        var openthisform = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Form;
        Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>().First(f => f is openthisform).Activate();
    }`
```

Comment: Why you cannot use this approach?

Comment: I get Constant value is expected error

Comment: Please add some more info. On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>().First(f => f is openthisform).Activate();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already opened the form and know its name then you just need to retrieve it from the Application.OpenForms using the name string

```
var form = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == fname);
if(form != null) form.Activate();
```